# html5 article jquery mixitup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, portfolio

I've a problem with my portfolio and the mixitup to filter the article in the section.  I don't know if the problem is that the `grid` div is not a top level element or that i use section and articles instead of a `ul - li` list. I've done the GettingStarted `http://mixitup.io/#Documentation` on there Website several times but I don't find the issue with my code. Have a look at my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2EP9u/1/). I found a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/QtQnB/)! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your jsfiddle example is, that there is no jQuery defined.

In the top left corner of site please choose jquery version in this block: "Frameworks & Extensions". 1.11.0 version is nice with it.

But if you meaned that your sorting doesn't work fine, so please synchronise your "data-filters" with classes in blocks.

For example:
    Lalala
    
    This will be shown when Lalala pressed.

Data-filter = selector of the class you should put near "mix" class.

Best regards, Hope you'll make it work! :)